# Linear regression cost function

Tags: regression, loss-functions

I'm looking at plain linear regression was wondering about the specifics of the cost function.

> The cost function associated with simple linear regression is given by:
>
> $$J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2n}\sum_{1=1}^n(y_i - \theta^tx_i)^2$$

Where does the ($\tfrac{1}{2n}$) term come from? Why not just $\tfrac{1}{n}$ so we achieve the average?

Comment: so the 2 doesn't matter to the result, but I believe its just so that when you differentiate it drops the 2 from the quadratic

Comment: The quotation is a little incorrect by stating this is "the" cost function: the given formula is one of a family of equivalent cost functions.  The reason is that cost functions are used for comparing things (via inequalities), whence (a) adding any constant makes no difference and (b) multiplying by any positive constant makes no difference.

Comment: It is a silly, anachronistic mathematical convenience that impedes actual understanding. One of several found throughout statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) minimizes squared error

$$
J(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \theta^T x_i)^2
$$

You might want to put $1/n$ in front, so that it's units don't depend on sample size $n$. The $1/2$ [comes from the derivative](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-rules.html)

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \big(x^2\big) = 2x
$$

and with

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \Big( \frac{1}{2} x^2 \Big) = x
$$

so putting $1/2$ in front makes writing the derivatives simpler because you don't need to add $2$ in front. $1/(2n)$ does both.

No matter which form you choose (sum of squared errors, $1/n$, $1/2$, $1/(2n)$), they have the same minimum, because multiplying function by a positive constant does not change its minimum, so they are equivalent.

Comment: Re "multiplying a function:" the constant must be *positive.*

Comment: @whuber good catch.